# Eclipse 2020.12 Now includes a JVM. How do you add a corporate certificate to it?

Tags: java, eclipse, certificate, ca

Eclipse 2020.12 now includes Oracle JDK 14 with the installation. This breaks Maven integration if your corporation has a CA (which most large places do).

How does one add a corporate certificate to the Eclipse JDK? I tried the following:

```
find /Applications/Eclipse.app -iname cacerts -exec keytool -importcert -alias emoneyusa-ecdsa -keystore {} -storepass changeit -file ~/Documents/certs/corp-ca.crt -trustcacerts -noprompt \;
```

However, I still get this problem when attempting to perform Maven functions inside Eclipse:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact xalan:xalan:jar:sources:2.7.2
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$4(MavenImpl.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.download(DownloadSourcesJob.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.downloadAttachments(DownloadSourcesJob.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.downloadMaven(DownloadSourcesJob.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.downloadFilesAndPopulateToUpdate(DownloadSourcesJob.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.lambda$0(DownloadSourcesJob.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.run(DownloadSourcesJob.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Contains: Failure to transfer xalan:xalan:jar:sources:2.7.2 from https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/xxx-all was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of xxx-all has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact xalan:xalan:jar:sources:2.7.2 from/to xxx-all (https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/xxx-all): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer xalan:xalan:jar:sources:2.7.2 from https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/xxx-all was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of xxx-all has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact xalan:xalan:jar:sources:2.7.2 from/to xxx-all (https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/xxx-all): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.lambda$4(MavenImpl.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:772)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.resolve(MavenImpl.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.download(DownloadSourcesJob.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.downloadAttachments(DownloadSourcesJob.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.downloadMaven(DownloadSourcesJob.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.downloadFilesAndPopulateToUpdate(DownloadSourcesJob.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.lambda$0(DownloadSourcesJob.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1374)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.DownloadSourcesJob.run(DownloadSourcesJob.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

What clued me in was Eclipse reports this JDK, which is funny because I only have AdoptOpenJDK11 installed:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.17.0.I20200902-1800
java.version=14.0.2
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/xxx/.eclipse_keyring
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/xxx/.eclipse_keyring
```

Comment: When you use `keytool` does it show the imported certificate inside the cacerts in Eclipse provided JDK?

Comment: The embedded Java is inside a plugin and that is specified in the [`eclipse.ini` where you can also specify a different Java to be used to run Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM). When using the _Eclipse Installer_ you can choose whether you want an embedded Java or using a Java installed on your system.

Comment: So I tried changed the JVM in the Eclipse.ini and unbelievably I'm getting the same error

Comment: Please show your `eclipse.ini`. Make sure `-vm` and the Java location are two lines directly above the line `-vmargs`.

Comment: I *finally* got this to work by installing jdk15 and using the vm parameter `-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`. It didn't seem to want to work using the dylib, or I was doing something stupid

Answer (score 0):

Some time back I had the same problem and I struggled a lot and tried almost everything. The actual problem is and rally strange is, 1. First of all your valid cert should have been installed in your JRE/JDK. 2. Even if you have installed cert in your jdk which you are using, sometime it still doesn't work because if there are multiple jre installed on your machine, eclipse randomly pick one of the jre aand try to connect with your org's Nexus. And now here is the problem. If eclipse would pick up a jre which does not have the cert, it will fail to connect with repo. The solution is 1. Install certs in all your jres on your machine. 2. Delete other jres ecept one whihc you are using and having valid cert. In my team, many team members had this problems, and we had solved with the solutions what I suggested. Try this and let me know if still there is any problem.

Comment: Eclipse does not randomly pick one of the JRE. [In the `eclipse.ini` you can specify a JRE to be used to run Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

Comment: @howlger that looks like it should work but it didn't. I had tried the same. The only solution was what I had mentioned.

Comment: It works for sure. Common mistakes are two have one instead of two lines and not having these two lines directly before `-vmargs`. Of course, you can also delete all other JREs.